# Regex contents outside of two tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to extract contents that lie outside two sets of html tags.

The HTML is set up like so:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    <small class="text-muted pull-right">4.4</small>
    <i class="custom-icon"></i>
    desired content to retrieve
    <span class="text-muted">some other text here</span>
</div>
```

I need to retrieve the content "desired content to retrieve" which lies after the `</i>` and before the `<span class="text-muted">`.

I've tried:

```
$custom_regex= '#</i>(.*?)<span class="text-muted">#';

$text_scan = preg_match_all( $custom_regex, $content_to_scan, $text_array );
```

with no success. The `$text_array` variable returns empty.

I'm not that great with regex, so maybe my expression is incorrect for what I'm after.

Comment: Probably you need to enable the "dotall" option (or whatever it is called in PHP).

Comment: Simple. You **DON'T** use regexes to match/mangle html. Use a [DOM](http://php.net/dom) parser.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't usage of lookarounds be better?

```
(?<=<\/i>)\s*(.*?)\n.*(?=<span)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zK2wD8/8

Comment: Nice, this seems to be working - but I'm running into the same issue when I implement it. It seems to be only returning the instances with two`<span class="text-muted></span>`. When there is only one, they aren't present in the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on regex, try [this](https://regex101.com/r/zK2wD8/1).

```
/<\/i>\s*(.*?)\n.*<span class="text-muted"/g
```

Comment: If there is a second `<span class="text-muted"`, it doesn't seem to grab the text properly: https://regex101.com/r/zK2wD8/3 , is there some way to stop it at the first occurance of `<span class="text-muted`?

Comment: any reason this only returns the first occurrence? I see that global and mutli line is set in the modifier - https://regex101.com/r/zK2wD8/5 - never mind, if i remove m/s modifiers things work.

Comment: Sorry, it matched your first example, it was a little bit more complicated than that. It is because of s modifier.

Comment: I see that it's working well, and correct here: https://regex101.com/r/zK2wD8/7 but when I attempt to implement it it returns ONLY the instances with 2 `<span class="text-muted"></span>` elements. Am I missing something? This is the regex I have here:
`$regex_pattern = '/<\/i>(.*?)<span/';
$scan = preg_match_all( $regex_pattern, $content_to_scan, $text_array );
print_r( $text_array );`

Comment: `$regex_pattern = "/<\\/i>\\s*(.*?)\\n.*<span/"; `

Comment: I'm not sure, I up voted both. I'm trying to grab the contents of the last occurrence of text-muted, which seems to be working perfectly on regex101 (https://regex101.com/r/zK2wD8/10) but again when I implement it the contents are empty...confused as to what the difference.

Comment: No, I did not mean it like that. I was just surprised and I don't understand why. So I just hope that some will point my mistake for me to learn more. Thank you for your up vote, and I hope your troubles with implementation will solve soon.

Comment: You forgot `(?<=<span class="text-muted"\>)(.*?)(?=\<\/span\>.*?<\/div\>)`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that!